# AtomicIntegerArray without array clone

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm looking for a class that can access atomically certain positions of an integer array.

```
iarray[pos]   -> get and set atomic
```

Unfortunately the Java class AtomicIntegerArray clones the array if you use the constructor and there are no public static accessors.

Is there another way to have an atomic get/set of an array in Java ?

Using directly unsafe is an option, yes I know :-).

Comment: Can you make array of AtomicIntegers?

Comment: That's too much resource taking + only a few positions need to be atomic

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: atomic access to a position in an integer array ( atomic like volatile; same for all threads without a synchronize )

Comment: I mean, you can do a `toString` and turn that into an array.

Comment: @ic3 I didn't mean "how are you trying to solve your problem", I meant "what *is* your problem"?

Comment: 10/20 threads filling millions of this mini caches that when full will be flushed

Comment: Are you talking about volatility or atomicity here? Because `get and set atomic (aka volatile)` [is not correct](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.fi/2007/08/volatile-does-not-mean-atomic.html). Your question is very confusing, and the explanation about mini caches doesn't really shine much more light on it.

Comment: However if you're trying to optimize for performance with millions of these, then `Unsafe` is your best bet.

Comment: remove the volatile, you're right.

Comment: that was our guess, Unsafe

Answer (score 0):

If you are treating some indices different than others (i.e. some need to be accessed atomically, others not so much) then perhaps a single array is the wrong data structure here.  You might do better keeping your non-atomic-access values in a `List` and keep the atomic-needed ones in a second `List` wrapped by `Collections.synchronizedList()`.

Comment: the question is without a synchronized for performance reasons